# Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground() only on Android 11 Samsung devices

Tags: android, android-service, samsung-mobile, android-11

I am getting this crash for only Samsung devices running android 11. Apparently the application is calling `startForegroundService(intent)` and requiring me to post a notification for the user to know that I am running a foreground service, but this call to `startForegroundService(intent)` was never made in the app source code, is it possible that Samsung made a custom implementation of android 11 and automatically calls `startForegroundService(intent)` whenever I call `startService(intent)`?

Stack trace

```
Context.startForegroundService() did not then call Service.startForeground(): ServiceRecord{4ab4323 u0 {app package name}/{library package name}.player.PlayerService}
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2240)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:246)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8506)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:602)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1130)
```

I start the service using `context.startService(intent)` and the service is started in OnResume of the application and the context is the application context.

Also here is how the service is declared in the manifest

```
 <service
            android:name=".player.PlayerService"
            android:exported="false"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:stopWithTask="false">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
  </service>
```

Update: I found the reason where the call to `startForegroundService(Intent)` is made, I am using the following receiver from android to help handle actions control devices like headphone buttons, so since I converted the app to androidx it started using the new `MediaButtonReceiver`

```
 <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

This is the code that is executed when the Receiver receives an event

```
@Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (intent == null
                || !Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())
                || !intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Ignore unsupported intent: " + intent);
            return;
        }
        ComponentName mediaButtonServiceComponentName =
                getServiceComponentByAction(context, Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
        if (mediaButtonServiceComponentName != null) {
            intent.setComponent(mediaButtonServiceComponentName);
            startForegroundService(context, intent);
            return;
        }
        ComponentName mediaBrowserServiceComponentName = getServiceComponentByAction(context,
                MediaBrowserServiceCompat.SERVICE_INTERFACE);
        if (mediaBrowserServiceComponentName != null) {
            PendingResult pendingResult = goAsync();
            Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();
            MediaButtonConnectionCallback connectionCallback =
                    new MediaButtonConnectionCallback(applicationContext, intent, pendingResult);
            MediaBrowserCompat mediaBrowser = new MediaBrowserCompat(applicationContext,
                    mediaBrowserServiceComponentName, connectionCallback, null);
            connectionCallback.setMediaBrowser(mediaBrowser);
            mediaBrowser.connect();
            return;
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find any Service that handles "
                + Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON + " or implements a media browser service.");
    }
```

You can see that it actually starts a foreground service, I am still investigating the crash but at least I know that a foreground service is started in the app.

Also, this crash does not only happen in Samsung like I thought, crashlytics reporting grouped Samsung crashed together because its a crash from the android platform, other instances of the same crash happens less frequently so they were way down in the crash list on firebase.

Comment: Hey, I am also facing the same problem. Did you get any solution yet ?

Comment: @vishusrivastava are you building a media player application?

Comment: yes, There is a podcast feature in app.

Comment: you just have to make sure that your application is posting a notification when a foreground service is started. Like most answers have stated.

Comment: My case is kinda different because I did not start a foreground service in the app, however androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver is calling foreground when the play button from a headphone is clicked and my app was the last app that played audio.

Answer (score 3):

## Update

### Possible reason

After you provided more code, it's still unclear if you call `startForeground()` in your `PlayerService` or not. It looks like you don't, and that's why you're seeing the crash. On the other hand, if this crash is only happening on Android 11, then you may also have a different problem.

### Sample code

I just made a simple app to reproduce a crash for `PlayerService` if `startForeground()` is not called. Maybe it will be helpful to you.

#### app/build.gradle

Add a dependency to use the androidx `MediaButtonReceiver`

```
...
implementation "androidx.media:media:1.2.1" 
...
```

#### AndroidManifest.xml

```
...
    <service
        android:name=".PlayerService"
        android:exported="false"
        android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

    <receiver android:name="androidx.media.session.MediaButtonReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>   
...
```

#### MainActivity.java

Emulate the media button event as below

```
...
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    intent.setClass(this, MediaButtonReceiver.class);
    intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT, "test");
    sendBroadcast(intent);
}
...
```

#### PlayerService.java

```
public class PlayerService extends Service {

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        MediaButtonReceiver.handleIntent(null, intent);

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

#### Fix

By adding `startForeground()` to `onCreate()` the problem gets fixed. Please note that the way I prepare parameters and use the method is **a draft only**. For detailed information, please check the official documentation [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/foreground-services).

```
...
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        Notification testNotification = new Notification();
        int testId = 1;
        startForeground(testId, testNotification);
    }
...
```

Answer (score -2):

for some foreground services that need to do works that need to access `location`, `microphone`, `mediaProjection`, `phoneCall`, `camera`, `dataSync`, `connectedDevice` and `mediaPlayback`, you must specify `"foregroundServiceType"` in manifest and set `ServiceInfo` for service when calling `startForeground` in service. I think this solves your problem.

**Edit**

You should start your `service` like this in your `onStartCommand` of your service:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification)
        }
        else{
            startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification, ServiceInfo.FOREGROUND_SERVICE_TYPE_MEDIA_PLAYBACK)
        }
```

are you do it?